Lebesgue Integral Properties
I have been following the Functional Analysis course on MIT open course and we are covering the Lebesgue integral. The prof teaching the course has left this question as an exercise (but its used in his proof of the monotone convergence theorem).
The question is to prove:
$$
\int_A f=\int_E \chi_A \cdot f,
$$
where $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $E$, and $A$ is a measurable subset of $E$
I have been trying to come up with a solution but I have not gotten anywhere (especially since we later use this result to prove the monotone convergence theorem).
Can someone please help me find a way to do it. Thanks!

Can you show it's true when $f$ is a simple function?  That takes you almost all the way.

I did show its true for simple functions but I don't know how to proceed from there without using Monotone Convergence theorem

I'm not sure why you are concerned with the monotone convergence theorem.  It wouldn't even help here.  Instead just look at the definition of the Lebesgue integral.
